# MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler does not support JDK dynamic proxies

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jmx

Recently I added JMX support to my Spring web application.

This works fine for beans with `@Component`, however,  for some services there seems to be a problem when adding `@ManagedResource`

I have a spring service annotated with `@Service` method.
I'm trying to add JMX to that service using `@ManagedResource` but it seems like spring is having troubles registering the beans:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter': Invocation of init method
failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable
to register MBean [...] with key 'appAnalysisServiceImpl'; nested
exception is org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExportException:
Could not create ModelMBean for managed resource [
     l@6142152] with key 'myservice'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler does
not support JDK dynamic proxies - export the target beans directly or
use CGLIB proxies instead
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
```

From the exception message it seems like spring requires a special exporter for this kind of class.
How do i export the bean directly without writing my own exporter ?

Answer (score 0):

If your service uses @Transactional then Spring won't be able to create a ModelBean since the service is proxied.